# Restrict whole WP site access except few pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security

I want to do this: block whole site (say abc.com) but allow only few page like abc.com/gamma and abc.com/alfa.

Comment: deny from all in .htaccess ?

Comment: Where's your efforts? Have you made any? We're here to observe non-functioning code. There's no code here. What do I do?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy.. Sorry I don't have any code because I don't know how/from where to start.

Comment: Is there a WP plugin to permit/deny access to WP posts/pages?

Comment: There is no plugin for that. The only solution I can think of is: Redirect all users to a landing page and restrict the to visit (using redirection) home page (+ other pages you do not want them to visit). Like check if current postid is in array of page ids we want to block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it via `.htaccess`, as @Droid said. All you have to do is to replace `file.php` with the unique file you want to allow and add more of them if you want so.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files "file.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I need to restrict few Wordpress pages not any .php file. Any suggestions for that.